# Losing value while instancing new object

Tags: javascript, canvas, web

I'm trying to draw lines in HTML Canvas using Javascript.

So overall how it's supposed to work:
Event Listener to 'mousedown' starts the process, creates the object in 'createLine' function and update it's dimensions and orientation in the event 'mousemove'. When I let go (meaning the event mouseup) the object is done and pushed into an array (again on the function 'createLine').

What's happening:
I've watched the values all over (mouse positions) and it seems that they disappear whenever I create the object. And it's never shown on screen. But they are stored on the 'figures' array but in both beggining and ending positions on the same place.

See code Below:

```
function Ponto (_mouse){
    this.x = _mouse.x
    this.y = _mouse.y
    this.id = 'Ponto'
    this.color = 'black'
    this.clicks = 1
}

Ponto.prototype.draw = function(canvas, context){
    context.beginPath()
    context.rect(this.x, this.y, 1, 1)
    context.stroke()
}

//Line class
function Linha(_pointIn, _pointFin){
    this.pointIn  = _pointIn
    this.pointFin = _pointFin
    this.name = 'Linha'
    this.color = 'black'
    this.isDrawing = true
}

Linha.prototype.draw = function(canvas, context){
    context.beginPath()
    context.strokeStyle = this.color
    context.lineWidth = '1'
    context.moveTo(this.pointIn.x, this.pointIn.y)
    context.lineTo(this.pointFin.x, this.pointFin.y)
    context.stroke()
}

function getClicks(){
    return mouse    
}

var canvas    = document.getElementById('canvasCG')
var ctx       = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.lineWidth = 1

var figures = new Array()
var click1  = undefined
var click2  = undefined

var tempFigure = undefined
var isDrawing  = 0

var mouse = {x:0, y:0}

function clearCanvas(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
    ctx.fillRect = (0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
}

function resetVariables(){
    click1 = undefined
    click2 = undefined
    tempFig = undefined
    isDrawing = 0
}

//Mouse Move event
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft
    mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop

    clearCanvas()
    for(i=0; i<figures.length; i++){
        figures[i].draw(canvas, ctx)
    }

    if(isDrawing == 1 && tempFigure != undefined){
        if(tempFigure.name == 'Linha')
            tempFigure.pointFin = mouse
        tempFigure.draw(canvas, ctx)
    }
}, false)


canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    isDrawing = 1
    click1 = getClicks()

    if(isDrawing == 1){
    click1 = getClicks()
    click2 = getClicks()
    createLine(click1, click2)
    }
}, false)

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
    isDrawing = 0
    click2 = getClicks()
    if(tempFigure.name == 'Linha')
    createLine(click1, click2)
}, false)


function createLine(click1, click2){
    if(isDrawing==1){
        tempFigure = new Linha(click1, click2)
    }else{
        figures.push(tempFigure)
        resetVariables()
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could create a simple plunker demonstrating the problem. Also, your code is not complete (Ponto class, canvas variable, etc.).

Comment: Sorry it's just that they are all over the place. Will edit in a bit.

Comment: Change the getClick function to function `getClicks(){ return {x : mouse.x, y : mouse.y};    }` as currently you are returning the referance to the same object so that `click1` and `click2` are the same and both referance the mouse. Thus if you change anything in `mouse` you also change `click1` and `click2`

Comment: @Blindman67 Thank you very much! It was indeed the getClicks function. I changed it to: 
function getClicks(){
  return pos = {x: mouse.x, y: mouse.y}
}
Been here for almost 12 hours. Barely started learning JS. Thanks!

Comment: @ThAS Cool, just a word of warning that using a variable without an explicit declaration will automatically place it in global scope. Thus `return pos = ...` will create a global variable called `pos`  For beginners I always recommend that you use the directive `"use strict";` that is placed at the first line of a script tag / file / or first line of a function. It forces stricter parsing and execution rules and would throw an `Assignment to undefined variable` error on the new function because `pos` is undefined. Using strict mode will help avoid many gotyas.

Comment: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/ This link explains it really well and should be able to solve your problem :)